# Difference between parameters "amount" and "amount=0", in this context?

Tags: ruby

What's the difference that the parameter "amount" being defined to 0 has on the overall instance creation in this context, since the code below the commented line does the same thing with out "amount=0"?

```
class Account
    attr_accessor :balance
    def initialize(amount=0)
        self.balance = amount
    end
    def +(x)
        self.balance += x
    end
    def -(x)
        self.balance -= x
    end
    def to_s
        balance.to_s
    end
end

acc = Account.new(20)
acc -= 5
puts acc
```

---

```
class Account
    attr_accessor :balance
    def initialize(amount)
        self.balance = amount
    end
    def +(x)
        self.balance += x
    end
    def -(x)
        self.balance -= x
    end
    def to_s
        balance.to_s
    end
end

acc = Account.new(20)
acc -= 5
puts acc
```

I'm a beginner. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Specifying `amount = 0` in the parameter list make the `amount` parameter become optional (with `0` as its default value).

If you don't specify `amount` argument, it will be `0`.

```
account = Account.new  # without amount argument
account.balance # => 0

account = Account.new 10  # with amount argument
account.balance # => 10
```

Comment: Oh... i forgot about it. Yeah. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is:

The first class sets the default value

```
    class Account
        attr_accessor :balance
        def initialize(amount=0)
            self.balance = amount
        end
        ... class omitted

    end

    account = Account.new
    account.balance # should be equal to 0
```

```
      class Account
        attr_accessor :balance
        def initialize(amount)
            self.balance = amount
        end
      ... class omitted

      end

      account = Account.new nil
      account.balance # should be equal to nil
```